# Resize an extended partition to the whole drive

Tags: partition

I previously had the following partitions on my `sda`:

```
- - /home
  - /var
  - /tmp
- swap
```

Now I deleted `/var`, `/tmp` and the swap partition of that drive. This leaves me with around 35G of empty space. I tried booting the computer with Kubuntu 12.04 and use the partition tool to resize it, but it gave errors about being unable to set the partition geometry. This is the current state of the system:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0719ee6e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda2            2046   593893375   296945665    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5            2048   554829823   277413888   83  Linux
```

I would like to use `sda` completely for `/home` without reformatting the drive. Those 35G are not worth moving the data from and to the device, I would say currently. Is there a way to resize without loosing the data?

Comment: Why don't you just extend the size of `sda5` to take up the entire size of `sda2`?

Comment: The partition starts at `2048`. Just create a new empty partition table with `fdisk`, make sure to create a partition that starts at the same place and uses the full disk size. `fdisk` may even use 2048 as default starting point nowadays.

Comment: @terdon I tried to do that, but the KDE partition tool gave me the described error.

Comment: @frostschutz that sounds pretty cavalier, is it not a problem that the 2048 partition is within an extended one?

Comment: @queueoverflow, it's only a problem if you hardcoded the `/dev/sda5` name somewhere rather than using UUIDs. In which case you also have to update your `/etc/fstab` or whatever.

Comment: frostshutz's idea would work. It does not matter if the you completely delete and recreate the partition (even with a different number, and not as an extended partition). All that matters is that the new partition start at the exact same point. But this is a somewhat advanced technique (and I would not use a "friendly" tool like the KDE one to do it), and gparted would be safer if you're not comfortable with the task.

Comment: What is the exact text of the error message about the partition geometry?

Comment: If you follow frostshutz's idea: after having resized the partition, you might want to resize the filesystem (via resize2fs or analogous program) to extend it over the new area of the partition.

Comment: Note that some filesystems (btrfs, zfs) allow for adding devices to a filesystem: if you can not extend the partition, you may create a new one and add it as a second device.

Answer (score 2):

I would download [GParted Live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) or [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=start) and burn it to a DVD/USB thumb drive and boot my system with it.

Once booted you can launch `parted` and extend the  `/dev/sda2 partition as needed. You can also delete partitions etc. from this tool too.

[image: ss #1]

Comment: It can be difficult to find a free download of Parted Magic - the only download link on that site is behind a $5 paypal "donation".  I have found Parted Magic on various bit-torrent sites, but I'd recommend the GParted Live CD instead http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

Comment: or since queueoverflow mentioned ubuntu, just run `apt-get install gparted` and then `sudo gparted`